# What is the utility and risk of the option -D in rsync --archive?

Tags: rsync, backup, devices

I use `sudo rsync --archive --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*",/lost+found}` a lot for backups so I want to be sure of what it does.

According to the `rsync` man page, `--archive` or `-a` is equivalent to  `-rlptgoD`.  All this options are fine and clear for me, except `-D` equivalent to `--devices --specials`, that are explained in [Unix files types, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types).

I have never seen the effect of `-D`, copying device and special files is completely out of my present understanding.

In which case could `-D` be useful for archiving?

Should I just write `-rlptgo`(no `-D`) to prevent unexpected effects?

While writing this, I have the idea that `sudo rsync --archive --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*",/lost+found}` could be replaced by `sudo rsync -rlptgo`, because devices and specials are roughly covered by the exclude; in particular, devices are exactly `"/dev/*"`.

Comment: You could create special device files like `/dev/zero` pretty much wherever you want using `mknod`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/562341/70524 (You probably may not have, but when making a whole system backup, it's worth considering that something you use may have)

Comment: That is an interesting example: compare `sudo rsync /dev/zero toto` and `sudo -D rsync /dev/zero toto` and `cp /dev/zero toto`.  `rsync -D` transfers `/dev/zero` nicely whereas `cp` fills the target with zeros.

Comment: I am still looking for a case when `-D` would be dangerous.

Comment: You could use `rsync -a --no-D ...`

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE Regarding your most recent comment here, it's rather the other way around; You _want_ to use `-D`, because not using `-D` could have unwanted consequences if you are copying directories containing device files, as you yourself noticed in the other comment.